# Causing a docker container to stop

Tags: docker, go

I have a docker container that runs a go program along the following lines

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

for {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        fmt.Printf("woke up!\n")

    }
```

}

The docker documentation states that when we do `docker stop <container id>` docker will let the container do a graceful shutdown within 10 seconds window and then try to kill it by force by sending a different signal. Since my code has an infinite loop I am not clear that when I run this program in my custom docker image, how and why is my container shutting down instantly.

Also, once I know why it is shutting down, how can I tweak my go program to not shutdown and let docker do a force shutdown.

I am basing my understanding of `docker stop` from
[docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/)

And it has the text that states: `The main process inside the container will receive SIGTERM, and after a grace period, SIGKILL.`

To be precise, is there a way I can

- Tweak my code where the SIGTERM is ignored and docker daemon has to do a SIGKILL eventually to the container
- Tweak my code where I can cause SIGKILL also to not cause the container to shutdown(I understand that in linux, process cannot catch or ignore SIGKILL). But is it possible to be able to disregard SIGKILL so that my code fools the docker daemon and the container won't shut down?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @BernardoDuarte, I edited and added my question more explicitly

Comment: So signals are handled by the kernel, not the container, so it has nothing to do with code unless you add signal handling code that talks to kernel in *go*.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Docker question, it's in how Go handles signals like SIGTERM.

https://gobyexample.com/signals

Basically, using signal.Notify will allow you to act on SIGTERM and do exactly what you want, including ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

How about something along the lines of this? It uses https://github.com/syossan27/tebata for signal handling. Example below will allow to be stopped by CTRL+C but will "resist" being killed by `SIGTERM` or `SIGKILL`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/syossan27/tebata"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func resist() {
    fmt.Println("Don't shut me down man!")
}

func main() {

    // Allow to be stopped by hitting CTRL+C
    c := tebata.New(syscall.SIGINT)
    c.Reserve(os.Exit, 1)

    // Catch SIGTERM and SIGKILL and do nothing
    t := tebata.New(syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGKILL)
    t.Reserve(resist)

    // Print a message every 2 seconds
    for {
        select {
        case <- time.After(2 * time.Second):
            fmt.Println("Nothing happened...")
        }
    }
}
```